# Portable camera with bluetooth or some other wireless technology support

Tags: video-camera, camera, mobile-phone, arduino, microcontroller

I want to find a tiny camera or camera module that can stream its videos via Bluetooth or other wireless technology. I want to use that camera as an accessory that can be attached to a body part. The video quality is not important. Important is that I can stream the videos with a mobile device via wireless technology while carrying this camera as an accessory. Any suggestions?

P.S. You can also suggest two separate parts that I could put together to achieve this goal, e.g. camera and bluetooth module separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Bluetooth, but wifi, therefore it qualifies for "other wireless technology, the "aiball" camera comes in as a candidate. Available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AYO96I4), as well as a few other locations, it doesn't come in with high praises via the reviews.

[image: aiball camera]

Here's the better part of this answer. Once you visit the Amazon link, you see other small wireless cameras that may give you the solution in a better manner than the aiball cam.